# How to automatically increase the Microsoft KMS Server counter above the threshold for Office products?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, windows-activation

KMS server counter always drop beneath the "activation threshold" and it's very frustrating increasing it manually (above 25 for OS and 5 for Office activations).

```
C:\Users\Administrator> cscript c:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs /dli all | findstr count
 Current count: 5
 Current count: 1
 Current count: 1
 Current count: 1
 Current count: 5
 Current count: 5
 Current count: 1
 Current count: 5
 Current count: 5
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

[py-kms's client](https://github.com/SystemRage/py-kms/blob/master/py-kms/pykms_Client.py) can do exactly this as documented [here](https://py-kms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Usage.html#pykms-client-py). Just add a scheduled task(s) to your KMS server:

```
python.exe pykms_Client.py <kms server IP> -m Office2010
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, I also found there is a bat file in this link "[How to increase KMS current count (count is insufficient)](http://woshub.com/how-to-increase-kms-server-current-count/)".

Comment: @Emily that script only works with counters of Windows7/10 but not of Office products. That's exactly why I had to find a new solution.